# property seems to be empty in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view controller which contains some data. There is an action button:

```
- (IBAction)readMorePressed:(id)sender {
    DetailedItem *itemVc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Item"];;

    itemVc.postTitle = self.postTitle;
    itemVc.category = self.category;
    itemVc.content = self.content;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:itemVc animated:YES];

}
```

As you can see, I try to set the `title`, the `category` and the `content` properties.

`self.postTitle`, `self.category` and `self.content` are not `nil`, confirmed via 
debugging)

Though, at the `viewDidLoad` method of the `DetailedItem` view controller, the `_postTitle`, `_category` and `_content` properties seem to be `nil`, so I cannot present them in the UI.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Perhaps `viewDidLoad` is being called before you set the properties.

Comment: so when/where should I try to set them?

Comment: First confirm if it's true or not.

Comment: What are the types of postTitle, category and content?

Comment: @rmaddy yes that's true, confirmed also via debugger.

Comment: @DanielZhang everything is NSString

Comment: You can't change when you set the properties so you need to change when you use them.

Comment: I need to use them at the very beginning of the view controller so that I can show their data to the UI

Comment: @koslib, it seems like your strings aren't getting set in the label or whatever you are using to display them in your `itemVC` view controller. Try setting them in `viewWillAppear:` in your `DetailedItem` view controller.

Comment: @DanielZhangs unfortunately same thing happens when I try to display them in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: @koslib, can you post the relevant code where you are updating your UI?

Comment: sure, https://gist.github.com/koslibpro/f0f82390869e18cb208b

Comment: @koslib, all of your code looks fine to me. The only other thing to check would be the connection of your views on `DetailedItem`.

Comment: Also make sure that the properties are `strong` not `weak`

Comment: do you have any special setter for those properties? are those accessing the view controllers's view? are you accessing the view controllers's view in the DetailedItem init methods?

Comment: @RichTolley they are all strong

Comment: @pablobart no, nothing special, neither special setters neither doing anything inside the init method, only within the `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillLoad`

Comment: @DanielZhang I think the connections to my view are okay, because when I try to hard-code set values, ex `self.title.text = @"something"`, it appears correctly on the UI

Comment: @koslib, that was a good way of verifying the views. I’m sure you are close to solving the problem.

Comment: The pattern I use in situations like this is as follows: 1) Check in viewDidLoad and setup UI as needed if property is set.  2) Write a custom setter for the property that will update the same UI item(s) as viewDidLoad.  This way I am sure that whichever order things happen, the UI is correct.

Comment: have you check in button action that itemVc have all properties value?

Comment: @jatin, yes I've checked that and all properties are correctly set there